# Extremely simple project crashes Xcode at compile time

Tags: xcode5, xcode6

I'm not the most experienced programmer in the world so before I file a bug I'd like to know whether I'm doing something stupid here.

[This project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5896473/test.zip) crashes clang on Xcode 5.1.1 (5B1008) as well as Xcode 6.0 (6A215l) at compile time. FWIW, creating a new project in Xcode 6 does not automatically add a .pch file anymore to the project....

```
Process:         Xcode [17263]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.1.1 (5085)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-5085000000000000~10
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 520942841
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [180]
Responsible:     Xcode [17263]
User ID:         503

PlugIn Path:       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libclang.dylib
PlugIn Identifier: libclang.dylib
PlugIn Version:    ??? (503.0.40)

Date/Time:       2014-05-11 22:04:11.818 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C1021)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  5F0DE60E-4FAE-AAC4-8BB3-B2A90D648B2A


Crashed Thread:  5  Dispatch queue: IDEIndex PCH Creation Lock

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000106a21000

VM Regions Near 0x106a21000:
    Stack                  000000010699f000-0000000106a21000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 5
--> STACK GUARD            0000000106a21000-0000000106a22000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 6
    Stack                  0000000106a22000-0000000106aa4000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 6

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00007fff8db72a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib             0x00007fff8db71d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation           0x00007fff95687fc5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation           0x00007fff956875e9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation           0x00007fff95686f25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.HIToolbox                0x00007fff96684a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
6   com.apple.HIToolbox                0x00007fff966847b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
7   com.apple.HIToolbox                0x00007fff966845bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
8   com.apple.AppKit                   0x00007fff96bc33de _DPSNextEvent + 1434
9   com.apple.AppKit                   0x00007fff96bc2a2b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit                0x0000000101262631 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 84
11  com.apple.AppKit                   0x00007fff96bb6b2c -[NSApplication run] + 553
12  com.apple.AppKit                   0x00007fff96ba1913 NSApplicationMain + 940
13  libdyld.dylib                      0x00007fff8be105fd start + 1


Thread 5 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: IDEIndex PCH Creation Lock
0   libclang.dylib                     0x0000000102c6d0d9 void llvm::BitstreamWriter::EmitRecordWithAbbrevImpl&lt;unsigned long long>(unsigned int, llvm::SmallVectorImpl&lt;unsigned long long>&, llvm::StringRef) + 809
1   libclang.dylib                     0x0000000102c6c867 void llvm::BitstreamWriter::EmitRecord&lt;unsigned long long>(unsigned int, llvm::SmallVectorImpl&lt;unsigned long long>&, unsigned int) + 71
2   libclang.dylib                     0x0000000102d90f25 clang::ASTWriter::WriteASTCore(clang::Sema&, llvm::StringRef, std::__1::basic_string&lt;char, std::__1::char_traits&lt;char>, std::__1::allocator&lt;char> > const&, clang::Module*) + 35045
3   libclang.dylib                     0x0000000102d8860e clang::ASTWriter::WriteAST(clang::Sema&, std::__1::basic_string&lt;char, std::__1::char_traits&lt;char>, std::__1::allocator&lt;char> > const&, clang::Module*, llvm::StringRef, bool) + 6830
4   libclang.dylib                     0x0000000102c189a3 clang::ASTUnit::Save(llvm::StringRef) + 691
5   libclang.dylib                     0x0000000102b9074f clang_saveTranslationUnit + 543
6   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation         0x00000001016663af -[IDEIndexClangTranslationUnit cxTranslationUnit] + 331
7   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation         0x00000001017cc11a +[IDEIndexClangDataSource translationUnitForPCHFile:arguments:session:create:] + 259
8   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation         0x0000000101895552 __90-[IDEIndex createPCHFile:arguments:hashCriteria:target:session:willIndex:translationUnit:]_block_invoke + 1739
9   libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff948102ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff94811166 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 39
11  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation         0x0000000100b705cf -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 95
12  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation         0x0000000101894932 -[IDEIndex createPCHFile:arguments:hashCriteria:target:session:willIndex:translationUnit:] + 919
13  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation         0x00000001016501f1 -[IDEIndexClangQueryProvider _createSharedTranslationUnitWithCurrentFileContentDictionary:index:] + 2601
14  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation         0x0000000101742414 __98-[IDEIndexClangQueryProvider codeDiagnosticsAtLocation:withCurrentFileContentDictionary:forIndex:]_block_invoke + 39
15  libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff948102ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff94811166 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 39
17  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation         0x0000000100b705cf -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] + 95
18  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation         0x000000010164f693 -[IDEIndexClangQueryProvider performClang:] + 140
19  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation         0x0000000101655579 -[IDEIndexClangQueryProvider codeDiagnosticsAtLocation:withCurrentFileContentDictionary:forIndex:] + 634
20  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation         0x00000001016552bd -[IDEIndex(IDEIndexQueries) codeDiagnosticsAtLocation:withCurrentFileContentDictionary:] + 109
21  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDESourceEditor     0x0000000107369727 __96-[IDEClangDiagnosticController _generateDiagnosticsForDocumentLocation:context:completionBlock:]_block_invoke + 462
22  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation         0x0000000100baf617 -[DVTOperation main] + 48
23  com.apple.Foundation               0x00007fff8dfbd8a1 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 631
24  com.apple.Foundation               0x00007fff8dfbd54b __NSOQSchedule_f + 64
25  libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff948102ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
26  libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff9481268f _dispatch_queue_drain + 451
27  libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff948139dd _dispatch_queue_invoke + 110
28  libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff94811fa3 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 75
29  libdispatch.dylib                  0x00007fff94813193 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
30  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x00007fff94362ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
31  libsystem_pthread.dylib            0x00007fff94365fb9 start_wqthread + 13
```

Comment: Interestingly, your project compiles under XCode 5.0.1, and gives the error message "Implicit declaration of function 'MY_DEBUG'is invalid in C99" at the line "MY_DEBUG(@"standard error: %@ %@ %@",self.path, self.arguments, s_err);"

Answer (score 0):

Your project has several mistakes. To solve that I'm going to write a step by step.

- Close your project
- Open directly your file test-Prefix.pch and comment the line #import "../../myStuff.h"
- Save the file and open your project
- Add the 3 files (myStuff.h, UTTask.h and UTTask.m) to your main    target
- Inside myStuff.h change the line #import "UTTask.m" by #import "UTTask.h"
- Replace the content of your test-Prefix.pch by

> ```
> #ifdef __OBJC__
>     #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
>     #import "myStuff.h"
> #endif
> ```

Then you have an issue with MY_DEBUG() method that is not defined so comment it (3 lines), while you have not defined it.

And that may works.